# What icon resources are relevant to windows 8?

Tags: delphi, delphi-4

What icon resources are most relevant to windows 8? I have currently the largest icon in res file 48x48 x256 colors, should I have a larger one for Win8?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing has changed in this area, at least for desktop apps, since Vista. In other words, you are already 5 years out-of-date. ;-)

The [guidelines that were introduced for Vista](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa511280.aspx) remain valid. For application icons the guidelines say:

> **Application icons and Control Panel items:** The full set includes 16x16, 32x32, 48x48, and 256x256 (code scales between 32 and 256).

The 256px icon should be a compressed PNG icon. The Delphi 4 resource compiler does not support such icons. You can use, for example, the MS resource compiler, `rc.exe`.

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera That's a GUI tool. Normally you want a console app in your build script to generate the .res files from the .rc files.